# How to get all the records from a table with 1 minute or 1 hourly interval in postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can i implement a query in postgreSQL to fetch the data with all columns at every 1 minute or 1 hourly internal.Attached screenshot of the data.
If we take 1 minute internal example then i will need 37th record, 50th record etc etc,

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetching data every minute from `my_table` based on the column `time` :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_trunc('minute', "time" :: timestamp )) *
      FROM my_table
     ORDER BY date_trunc('minute', "time" :: timestamp ), "time"
```

Fetching data every 30 seconds from `my_table` based on the column `time` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (d.date_interval) *
  FROM my_table AS t
 INNER JOIN 
     ( SELECT generate_series(date_trunc('minute', min(time)), max(time), interval '30 seconds') AS date_interval
         FROM my_table
     ) AS d
    ON d.date_interval <= t.time
   AND d.date_interval + interval '30 seconds' > t.time
 GROUP BY d.date_interval
 ORDER BY d.date_interval, t.time
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, with above query seconds are 00 is there a way it might have some value or it will always be 0? Also if i want to use above query for 30 second interval can you please let me know how to do it.

Comment: With the above query, if you ` SELECT date_trunc('minute', "time" :: timestamp )` then you get 00 as seconds, but if you `SELECT time` then you get the seconds of the first row ordered by `time` for every minute. For a 30 seconds interval, the solution approach may be different and I'm going to update the answer.